# Apache2 URL forwarding

Tags: apache-http-server, http, forwarding

If some one goest to  *.test.com/privacy the page need to redirect to *.test.com/hello/jsp/privacy.jsp

I tried

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /privacy to http://www.test.com/hello/jsp/privacy.jsp
```

But it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Since the page `http://www.test.com/hello/jsp/privacy.jsp` is in another vhost, this is reverse proxy setup. So specify flag `P` at the end of rewrite rule. Also you specify `ProxyPassReverse` directive.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule "^/privacy$" http://www.test.com/hello/jsp/privacy.jsp [NC,L,P]
ProxyPassReverse "/privacy" http://www.test.com/hello/jsp/privacy.jsp
```

More info about FLAGS here: [URL](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html)

Or you can just use `proxy pass`

```
ProxyPass /privacy http://www.test.com/hello/jsp/privacy.jsp
ProxyPassReverse /privacy http://www.test.com/hello/jsp/privacy.jsp
```